# Understanding EhCache with Spring/MyBatis

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching, ehcache, mybatis

I am using EhCache with Spring and MyBatis and need some clarification on how EhCache is working. I have the following configuration file for ehcache.

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false"
         monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000"
                  eternal="false"
                  timeToIdleSeconds="300"
                  timeToLiveSeconds="600"
                  diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
                  maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
                  diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
                  memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="false">
    </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

I am only configuring the default cache. If I am understanding this correctly when you add this line to a MyBatis mapper file it creates a new cache.

```
<cache type="org.mybatis.caches.ehcache.EhcacheCache" />
```

Which leads my to wonder does that inherit the properties from the default cache? If not what if anything is the purpose of configuring the default cache?

Is it best practice to create a cache for each piece of functionality / data, or one big cache?

Also I am trying to get away from XML, so I'm wondering if this could all be accomplished with Java Config?

I have the following Java Config, but there doesn't appear to be a way to configure the default cache with the Java Config method, so I'm wondering how well that will work, and if its a good option with working with MyBatis?

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig implements CachingConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration.setName(environment.getRequiredProperty("ehcache.name"));
        cacheConfiguration.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy(environment.getRequiredProperty("ehcache.memoryStoreEvictionPolicy"));
        cacheConfiguration.setDiskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds(environment.getRequiredProperty("ehcache.diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds", Integer.class));
        cacheConfiguration.setDiskSpoolBufferSizeMB(50);
        cacheConfiguration.setOverflowToDisk(true);
        cacheConfiguration.setDiskPersistent(true);
        cacheConfiguration.setMaxBytesLocalHeap("512000000");
        cacheConfiguration.setMaxBytesLocalDisk("2048000000");
        cacheConfiguration.eternal(false);
        cacheConfiguration.setTimeToIdleSeconds(1800);
        cacheConfiguration.setTimeToLiveSeconds(3600);
        cacheConfiguration.statistics(true);
        cacheConfiguration.logging(true);

        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
        config.addCache(cacheConfiguration);

        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    }

    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return new SimpleCacheResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
    }

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new SimpleCacheErrorHandler();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code of `org.mybatis.caches.ehcache.EhcacheCache, you will find that

1. It is internally creating a `CacheManager`. There is also no option of configuring the class(Class is marked as final) so that, we can make it use the Spring cache Manager.

   The best option for you would be to use Spring Method level caching and discontinue thinking of caching using `org.mybatis.caches.ehcache.EhcacheCache`

   Better use the spring annotation driven caching which means you don't have to use one big cache, but can use individual cache for each case.

Comment: Please look at this source for an implementation of caching using mybatis, https://github.com/eddumelendez/spring-dataaccess/tree/master/spring-dataaccess-mybatis.

Comment: The code example on GitHib is using the @Cacheable on the interface for MyBatis mapper, but does that use any of the settings defined in by the default cache in ehcache.xml? If I'm understanding correctly each method would be its own cache is that correct? Is is automatically named the method name, since we may need to flush it at some point?

Comment: Ohh I see the cache is named findAll